# Netty multithreading working group doesn't work

Tags: multithreading, netty

Based on the documentation https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html:

> // Tell the pipeline to run MyBusinessLogicHandler's event handler
>   methods
>   // in a different thread than an I/O thread so that the
>   I/O thread is not blocked by
>   // a time-consuming task.
>  
>   // If your business logic is fully asynchronous or finished very
>   quickly, you don't
>   // need to specify a group.
>  
>   pipeline.addLast(group, "handler", new MyBusinessLogicHandler());

this should provide multithreading for the handler. But actually it doesn't, please check the implemented example: https://github.com/oleg-sta/NettyExample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/netty/Main.java
In this example, HelloServerHandler receives messages one-by-one, why the workerGroup don't work?

Comment: Asked same question on github: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/10352, the answer were provided as below

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that most protocols need some sort of ordering which can't be guaranteed if we just pick a new thread for each message. That said you can archive what you want by using the `UnorderedThreadPoolEventExecutor` when adding a handler to the pipeline